# Additional profile claim not making it to client application

Tags: identityserver4

I have an additional claim called "spn".  It is configured as a claim on the profile identity resource table.  When I check the identity token it is not found there.  I have used the built in profile service as well as a custom profile service with the same results.  All of the other claims I have configured there and populated in the user claims table are working.

Is there something in the that is blocking this non-standard claim or some where else I need to configure it?

I am utilizing the latest version of identity server and EF as the backend with ASP.net Identity handling the user accounts.

Comment: I just intercepted the OnUserInformationReceived event.  I did see that the claims where there, but they are not making into the rest of the system.  Does .net only handle a set of default claims and custom claim types need to be handled differently?

Comment: You will likely have to utilize [`ClaimActionCollectionMapExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/Claims/ClaimActionCollectionMapExtensions.cs) when configuring your `OpenIdConnectOptions`. You can see some of the standard claim action mapping in [`OpenIdConnectOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L64)

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of where I can configure this?

Comment: Something like this might work for you:
`.AddOpenIdConnect(options => { options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("spn", "spn"); }`

Comment: Interesting that even standard "role" claim which is visible in the IdentityServer itself also isn't emitted into a token by default. More details [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1786)